# This code works, but how?

Tags: vba

I just wrote this function to read a series of email addresses from a linebreak-delimited text file.  And **it does work**, but that's not my question.

```
Function GetEmailArray(FileName As String) As String()
    Dim TempArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Open FileName For Input Access Read As #1
    Do While Not (EOF(1))
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve TempArr(i + 1)
        Line Input #1, TempArr(i + 1)
        Debug.Print TempArr(i + 1)
    Loop
    Close #1
    GetEmailArray = TempArr
End Function
```

Reading this, I would expect this to:

1. Read the first line, store it in TempArr(1)
2. Loop
3. Read the first line AGAIN, store it in TempArr(2)
4. Loop
5. Etc

I just can't figure out how the while loop goes to the next line in the text file.

Comment: NB you may want to use FreeFile() to generate the file numbers rather than hard-coding them as #1, #2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're holding a handle (#1) to the file from the point you call `Open`, until you call `Close`. Behind the scenes (on the O/S level), the handle retains a current file position as part of the file descriptor.

Comment: This is the first time I've used Open().  Yesterday, I was trying to write this by choosing a driver, setting up a connection string, writing a schema.ini file, creating a recordset using an ADODB connection, bleh.  This is much easier.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Your step 3 should be:

`3.` Read the next line from the file into TempArr(i + 1)

So you do not read in the first line again, the `line input` statement reads the line, and places the file-position on the next line.

Comment: I thought Step 3 was always "Profit!!"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the magic is happening on `Line Input #1, TempArr(i+1)`. It reads from file handle #1 to `TempArr(i+1)`. When it gets to the end of the file, `EOF(1)` will evaluate to true and terminate the `while` loop. How does the system know which is the next line? That's handled under the hood  for you, by `Line Input`.

Answer (score 0):

The Line Input function is altering the current line. Pretty tacky stuff.

Comment: Does Line Input really *alter* anything or does it just read from a file and store into a variable? Well, I guess it alters the target variable, in the sense that it populates it with data...

Comment: Tacky? I've never heard that word used before with code.  Please elaborate?

Comment: @Frustrated, By invoking "Access Read", I'm opening the file for Read-Only access.

Comment: @PowerUser: Yeah, when was the last time you saw code with rhinestones and leopard-print leggings and 10 pounds of pseudo-gold bling?

Comment: @PowerUser: That was my point. The *source* of the lines (the file) is **not** altered by reading it.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner It alters the current line in the sense that it alters the reference to the current line. Kinda like you tend to refer to objects in C# rather than references to objects.

Comment: "Tacky? I've never heard that word used before with code. Please elaborate?" Low quality. Cheap. Most obvious approach with minimal thought to the actual consequences. That sums up VBA as a whole, mind you.

Comment: @Rushyo: Thanks, that's clearer (but your initial answer wasn't).

Comment: @Rushyo: Low quality? Well, it does have an error handler, but I left that out of my post since it wasn't relevant to my question. And I'm not including any data validation code since it isn't important here.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Perhaps an overzealous attempt at efficiency, but again you won't see anyone referring to 'a reference to an object' in C# where 'object' will suffice. That includes in Microsoft documentation.